# Verify all drivers for all the devices are loaded in ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, drivers

Host,

```
Manufacturer: Supermicro
Model: SYS-1029U-TN10RT
```

ESXi,

```
Product: VMware ESXi
Version: 7.0.3
Build: Releasebuild-21424296
Update: 3
Patch: 85
```

Installed using iPXE, (not sure if relevant)

```
#!ipxe
kernel http://${boot_url}/bootx64.efi -c http://${boot_url}/boot.cfg
# bootx64.efi is the bootloader executable of esxi installer
boot
```

Host -> Manage -> Hardware -> PCI Devices contain a lot of grayed out devices, most of them seem to be related to CPU, is that due to missing drivers for them?
[image]

Information of one specific item from `esxcli hardware pci list` indicates `Module ID: -1, Module Name: None` while something that is known to have drivers indicates `Module ID: 50, Module Name: vmw_ahci`. Does that mean item mentioned first doesn't have drivers?

```
0000:00:00.0
   Address: 0000:00:00.0
   Segment: 0x0000
   Bus: 0x00
   Slot: 0x00
   Function: 0x0
   VMkernel Name: PCIe RP[0000:00:00.0]
   Vendor Name: Intel Corporation
   Device Name: Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers
   Configured Owner: VMkernel
   Current Owner: VMkernel
   Vendor ID: 0x8086
   Device ID: 0x2020
   SubVendor ID: 0x15d9
   SubDevice ID: 0x091c
   Device Class: 0x0600
   Device Class Name: Host bridge
   Programming Interface: 0x00
   Revision ID: 0x07
   Interrupt Line: 0x00
   IRQ: 255
   Interrupt Vector: 0x00
   PCI Pin: 0x00
   Spawned Bus: 0x00
   Flags: 0x3001
   Module ID: -1
   Module Name: None
   Chassis: 0
   Physical Slot: -1
   Slot Description:
   Device Layer Bus Address: p0000:00:00.0
   Passthru Capable: false
   Parent Device:
   Dependent Device:
   Reset Method: None
   FPT Sharable: false
   NUMA Node: 0
   Extended Device ID: 0
   Extended Device Name:
```